# Because the Dependent Role properties are not the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '*'

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I know this question is similar to some but my setup is different from those.  What is the correct configuration in EF with the following classes?

The issue here is `Team` has an optional `DivisionParticipant`, but `DivisionParticipant` has an optional `Team` also.

```
public class Team 
{
     [Key]
     public int Id {get;set;}
     public DivisionParticipant DivisionParticipant {get;set;}
}

public class DivisionParticipant
{
     [Key]
     public int Id {get;set;}

     public int? TeamId {get;set;}
     [ForeignKey("TeamId")]
     public Team Team {get;set;}
}
```

Error

Team_DivisionParticipant_Target: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'Team_DivisionParticipant_Target' in relationship 'Team_DivisionParticipant'. Because the Dependent Role properties are not the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '*'.

Comment: Is Team.DivisionParticipant the inverst of DivisionParticipant.Team.  ie for `Team t t.DivisionParticipant.Team == t;`  Or are these two _seperate_ relationships?

Comment: Yes its the same entity

Comment: Well multiple DivisionParticipants could have the same TeamId, so Team's Navigation property would need to be an ICollection<DivisionParticipant>, as indicated by the error message.

Comment: So there is no way to do a single entity?  This was converted from a 1:1 where the TeamID you see above was the ID but now we need to autoincrement DivisionParticipant's ID.  Having a collection wont kill us but would rather have a single property.

Comment: In EF6, no.  EF Core supports Alternate Keys, which also enables the model you're intending by marking DivisionParticipant.TeamId as an alternate key. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/alternate-keys And EF Core does not require .NET Core.

Comment: So you are saying I can use EF Core in my regular .NET project even though I’m not using Core?

Comment: Yep. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/full-dotnet/new-db

Comment: Awesome I’ll check it out.  I’ve done non mapped properties before which have worked. If I went this route of alternative keys do you have an answer to post with my classes? I can mark it as answered.

Comment: In your team class how come you do not have a FK to DivisionParticipant?

Comment: Cause it’s optional and not on the Team table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EF 6 does not support this, as EF 6 does not support Alternate Keys.  EF Core does, and EF Core can now be used from .NET Framework apps in addition to .NET Core apps.

This model works without additional configuration on EF Core, because:

> By convention, an alternate key is introduced for you when
>   you identify a property, that is not the primary key, as the target of
>   a relationship.

[Alternate Keys - EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/alternate-keys)

Comment: Just a quick question. I assume EF Core can do everything EF .NET can do?

Comment: "EF Core can do everything EF .NET can do?"  No.  It's not "EF 7" because it's a complete rewrite.  And currently it lacks some features that are in EF6, and vice versa.  Also it has completely new, and less-tested LINQ query generation engine.  As of 2.1 it's pretty good, but you need to test thoroughly when migrating.  Here's the feature comparison: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/efcore-and-ef6/features

Comment: Will EF 7 have this new feature?

Comment: There will probably never be an EF 7.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to achieve what you want is like this:

```
public class Team 
{
     [Key]
     public int Id {get;set;}
     public DivisionParticipant DivisionParticipant {get;set;}
}

public class DivisionParticipant
{
     [Key, ForeignKey("Team")]
     public int Id {get;set;}

     public Team Team {get;set;}
}
```

Whenever a one-to-one (or a one to zero-or-one) relationship is needed, the dependent end's (DivisionParticipant in your case) foreign key should be its primary key as well. If you do not do so, then you will receive this error:

> **Because the Dependent Role properties are not the key properties**, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '*'.

Comment: Yea but `Id` is an autoincrement.  I need a `TeamId` column on there dont I or can it live without it?

Comment: @MikeFlynn You want DivisionParticipant.Id to be autoincremented?

Comment: Unfortunately, that is the only way to do it. If it does not meet your needs, you need to make one side * and control it through your application. I have done so in the past by creating a partial class and then putting a single property which returns the `FirstOrDefault()` from the collection property.

Comment: Yes I do.  My example has TeamId as a property showing the FK.  I have seen your examples but I dont think your configuration works with what I need.

Comment: Yes I have done that before also with a NonMapped property and got it that way.

Comment: @MikeFlynn Cool sounds good. Sorry I could not be of more help.